# how to modify TNY264-based smps for different output current?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, circuit-design

In one of the reference applications for the TNY264 switcher, we can see the following circuit.

[image]

and in part of the circuit description we read:

> ... The output voltage is determined by the
>   sum of the optocoupler U2 LED forward drop (~1 V), and Zener
>   diode VR1 voltage. Resistor R8 maintains a bias current
>   through the Zener diode to ensure it is operated close to the
>   Zener test current. A simple constant current circuit is implemented using the VBE
>   of transistor Q1 to sense the voltage across the current sense
>   resistor R4. When the drop across R4 exceeds the VBE of
>   transistor Q1, it turns on and takes over control of the loop by
>   driving the optocoupler LED. Resistor R6 assures sufficient
>   voltage to keep the control loop in operation down to zero volts
>   at the output...

**But it is not very clear to me what component values I should change to get the same 5Vdc at the output but 2 amps instead of 500 ma.**

Does anybody have experience designing with this component that could help me to know what to change to achieve 5Vdc @ 2 amps at the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the chip. According to the datasheet, the TNY264 is only capable of 9W maximum output, even when adequately heatsinked and ventilated. Some of the other members of its family can handle >10W.

Answer (score 0):

As Dave has pointed out, some other chips in this family can be an option. I can recommend TNY268. But you will also need to redesign the transformer. Because switching frequency may differ from TNY264 to TNY268 (you need to check this) and your voltage and current needs are different. If switching frequency is the same for both then you should use the same number of turns with 1.8-2 times thicker wires.